# How to sum values of a struct in a nested array in a Spark dataframe?

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is in **Spark 2.1**, Given this input file:

`order.json

```
{"id":1,"price":202.30,"userid":1}
{"id":2,"price":343.99,"userid":1}
{"id":3,"price":399.99,"userid":2}
```

And the following dataframes:

```
val order = sqlContext.read.json("order.json")
val df2 = order.select(struct("*") as 'order)
val df3 = df2.groupBy("order.userId").agg( collect_list( $"order").as("array"))
```

df3 has the following content:

```
+------+---------------------------+
|userId|array                      |
+------+---------------------------+
|1     |[[1,202.3,1], [2,343.99,1]]|
|2     |[[3,399.99,2]]             |
+------+---------------------------+
```

and structure:

```
root
 |-- userId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- array: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- userid: long (nullable = true)
```

Now assuming I am given df3:

1. I would like to compute sum  of array.price for each userId, taking advantage of having the array per userId rows.
2. I would add this computation in a new column in the resulting dataframe. Like if I had done df3.withColumn( "sum", lit(0)), but with lit(0) replaced by my computation.

It would have assume to be straighforward, but I am stuck on both.  I didnt find any way to access the array as whole do the computation per row (with a foldLeft for example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to compute sum of array.price for each userId, taking advantage of having the array

Unfortunately having an array works against you here. Neither Spark SQL nor `DataFrame` DSL provides tools that could be used directly to handle this task on array of an arbitrary size without decomposing (`explode`) first.

You can use an UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}

val totalPrice = udf((xs: Seq[Row]) => xs.map(_.getAs[Double]("price")).sum)
df3.withColumn("totalPrice", totalPrice($"array"))
```

```
+------+--------------------+----------+ 
|userId|               array|totalPrice|
+------+--------------------+----------+
|     1|[[1,202.3,1], [2,...|    546.29|
|     2|      [[3,399.99,2]]|    399.99|
+------+--------------------+----------+
```

or convert to statically typed `Dataset`:

```
df3
  .as[(Long, Seq[(Long, Double, Long)])]
  .map{ case (id, xs) => (id, xs, xs.map(_._2).sum) }
  .toDF("userId", "array", "totalPrice").show
```

```
+------+--------------------+----------+
|userId|               array|totalPrice|
+------+--------------------+----------+
|     1|[[1,202.3,1], [2,...|    546.29|
|     2|      [[3,399.99,2]]|    399.99|
+------+--------------------+----------+
```

As mentioned above you decompose and aggregate:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{sum, first}

df3
  .withColumn("price", explode($"array.price"))
  .groupBy($"userId")
  .agg(sum($"price"), df3.columns.tail.map(c => first(c).alias(c)): _*)
```

```
+------+----------+--------------------+
|userId|sum(price)|               array|
+------+----------+--------------------+
|     1|    546.29|[[1,202.3,1], [2,...|
|     2|    399.99|      [[3,399.99,2]]|
+------+----------+--------------------+
```

but it is expensive and doesn't use the existing structure.

There is an ugly trick you could use:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{coalesce, lit, max, size}

val totalPrice = (0 to df3.agg(max(size($"array"))).as[Int].first)
  .map(i => coalesce($"array.price".getItem(i), lit(0.0)))
  .foldLeft(lit(0.0))(_ + _)

df3.withColumn("totalPrice", totalPrice)
```

```
+------+--------------------+----------+
|userId|               array|totalPrice|
+------+--------------------+----------+
|     1|[[1,202.3,1], [2,...|    546.29|
|     2|      [[3,399.99,2]]|    399.99|
+------+--------------------+----------+
```

but it is more a curiosity than a real solution.

Answer (score 6):

**Spark 2.4.0** and above

You can now use the [AGGREGATE](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#aggregate) functionality.

```
df3.createOrReplaceTempView("orders")
spark.sql(
    """
      |SELECT
      |    *,
      |    AGGREGATE(`array`, 0.0, (accumulator, item) -> accumulator + item.price) AS totalPrice
      |FROM
      |    orders
      |""".stripMargin).show()
```